# Write a program that takes 5 numbers as a rate input and print out all the inputs in a Highest to Lowest order

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, for-loop

The program must able to decide which rating is the highest and the lowest.

Test Case:

```
Rate 1: 237
Rate 2: 4303
Rate 3: -635
Rate 4: 715
Rate 5: 56
```

Test Output :

```
Ratings in Highest to Lowest order :

Rate 2
Rate 4
Rate 1
Rate 5
Rate 3

The Highest Rating is Rate 2 with the of 4303
The Lowest Rating is Rate 3 with the of -635
```

I TRIED THIS BEFORE BUT I CANT GET THE EXACT OUTPUT:

```
try {
    //Create Object for Scanner class to get input from keyword
    Scanner g = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the value of N: ");
    //Declaring array
    int inputValue = g.nextInt(), temp;
    //Get input from keyword
    System.out.print("Input Rating Value Below\n");
    int[]arr = new int[inputValue];
    //Get all input from keyword
    for(int i = 0, j= 1; i <= inputValue && j <= inputValue;i++, j++){
        System.out.print("Rate " + j + ":");
        arr[i]= g.nextInt();
    }
    //Sort the given ratings
    for(int m=0;m<arr.length;m++) {
        for(int n=m+1;n<arr.length;n++) {
            if(arr[m]<arr[n]) {
                temp = arr[m];
                arr[m]=arr[n];
                arr[n]=temp;
            }
        }
    }
    //Output of sorted ratings
    System.out.print("Ratings in Highest to Lowest: \n");
    for(int t: arr) {
        System.out.println("Rate : " + t);
    }
    //assign first element of an array to largest and smallest
    int min = arr[0];
    int max = arr[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] > max)
            max = arr[i];
        else if (arr[i] < min)
            min = arr[i];
    }

    System.out.println("The Highest Rating is "+ max);
    System.out.println("The Lowest Rating is " + min);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
static void heighestToLowestOrder(int[] input) {
    int length = input.length;
    int[] ordered = IntStream.range(0, length)
        .boxed()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(i -> input[(int) i]).reversed())
        .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
        .toArray();
    System.out.println("Ratings in Highest to Lowest order :");
    System.out.println();
    IntStream.of(ordered)
        .forEach(i -> System.out.printf("Rate %d%n", i + 1));
    System.out.println();
    System.out.printf("The Highest Rating is Rate %d with the of %d%n",
        ordered[0] + 1, input[ordered[0]]);
    System.out.printf("The Lowest Rating is Rate %d with the of %d%n",
        ordered[length - 1] + 1, input[ordered[length - 1]]);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] input = {237, 4303, -635, 715, 56};
    heighestToLowestOrder(input);
}
```

output:

```
Ratings in Highest to Lowest order :

Rate 2
Rate 4
Rate 1
Rate 5
Rate 3

The Highest Rating is Rate 2 with the of 4303
The Lowest Rating is Rate 3 with the of -635
```